# Azure DevOps Report for User Story Status History

Tags: azure-devops

We are using Azure DevOps to track our development work. I can open an individual story and see the history of changes and the chart of the status history. This is useful for an individual story, but doesn't allow me to identify trends and possibly highlight issues in our processes.

I would like to have a chart, or an export that shows the historical changes for all stories (within a date range, or some other filter) so I can discover:

1. How long does a story stay in each status, on average? (Q: Which statuses take the most time)
2. How many times is a story set to a status, on average? (Q: When and how often are we moving backward in the flow)
3. How many times does a story move backward for each team member? (Q: Where should we focus our training efforts)

I have searched within the dashboard, reports, and online for some way to get this information and either haven't used the right keywords, it doesn't exist, or I totally missed it.

Does anyone know if this type of information is available and how I can access it?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an easy way to accomplish this, unfortunately. Your best bet is going to be composing a Power BI report or Excel, whichever you're most familiar with. Even then, you're going to run into problems with **#2** and **#3**. Microsoft doesn't have an easily accessible way to query the history of each status among all work items.

However, **#1** is possible within PowerBI and Excel. Here are a few guides to get you started:

**Excel**

To import Queries into excel, you have to install a few things follow this guide to get started:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/office/track-work?view=azure-devops&tabs=open-excel

**Power BI**

To get started consuming Analytics views within Power BI, follow this guide:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/create-quick-report?view=azure-devops

Whether you're using PowerBI or Excel, the fields you'll want to include within your query or Analytics View will look like "**[STATUS] Date**", "Closed Date" for example. That will make them accessible within PowerBI, or Excel, depending on which you go with.

Once you have your data, you'll want to create reports that compare the status dates to determine how long a story stays within a status.

Answer (score 0):

> Azure DevOps Report for User Story Status History

Azure devops is not intended to be a time tracking tool. You could query the work item history with the TFS API and check the timestamps on when the state transitions occurred if you really wanted to.

So, Azure devops doesn't track the time spent on a per day basis. It keeps track of the total time spent. If you want a per person per day value, you'll have to go through the iterations/workitem history and calculate the running difference.

If you really looking for a TimeReporting for the work items of per person, I suggest that you take a look at a third party yool like Timetracker:

[Timetracker](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=7pace.Timetracker)

> New to version 5.0.! **Individual**, team, and custom reports powered by
> version 3 of the REST-based reporting API. 7+ customizable widget
> types that let you see data that you need, how you need it. In
> addition to the six default reports in Reporting, users can create
> custom reports for individuals or teams.

On the other hand, we could develop our scripts via REST API [Revisions - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/revisions/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to get the `System.State` change and `System.ChangedDate`, then compare the date to get the time in each status.